# SQL Server query timesout after running a few times, only fix is DROPCLEANBUFFERS or Restart SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a complex query that joins on tables that have large amounts of data. The query timesout after the application runs it a few times. The only ways I can get it working again are by **restarting SQL Server** or running:

```
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;
```

Can someone give me an idea of what things I should be looking into? I am trying to narrow down what needs to be done to fix this. Is there a way to completely disable caching for the query? It seems like the caching is what is making it timeout eventually.

Comment: SQL Server never times out a query. Is your app that cancels the query. Why did you tag the question `ssms`, is the query run from Management Studio? SSMS does not time out queries either.

Comment: You have a performance problem, so analyze it as such. [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/).

Answer (score 2):

TheGameiswar's suggestion of updating statistics is a very good idea. Though, you may want to investigate further even if updating statistics alleviates the timeout issue.

It sounds like you are getting a query plan that is only good for some of the parameters being sent to it, which could be caused parameter sniffing; particularly with heavily skewed data.

Have you tried adding `option (recompile)`to the query or `with recompile` if it is a procedure?

Have you checked the execution plan?

Reference:

- [Parameter Sniffing, Embedding, and the RECOMPILE Options - Paul White](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/08/t-sql-queries/parameter-sniffing-embedding-and-the-recompile-options)

Comment: Excellent link.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your query might have out of date statistics,try updating the statistics for all tables involved in the query,this presents SQLServer a good chance in getting right estimates which also lowers several grants

If this happens even after updating statistics ,try fine tuning the query

to update statistics ,use below query..also try running with full scan,even this might not be needed for all cases

```
UPDATE STATISTICS tablename with fullscan;
```

Comment: How do I go about updating statistics?